# Problem with the API-token from IBM TypeError

Tags: qiskit, programming

**English/Englisch**:
Hi, could anyone help me please?I have a problem with the API-token

```
line 8, in random_qubit

IBMQ.load_account('API-token is normally standing here but I delete it for the question')

TypeError: load_account() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

If someone has the solution or the same problem, please comment it below this question
And sorry for my bad english.

**German/Deutsch**:
Hey könnte mir wer bitte helfen? Ich hab ein Problem und zwar

```
line 8, in random_qubit

IBMQ.load_account('API-Token hab ich heraus gelöscht wegen Kommentar sonst würde hier der API-Token stehen')

TypeError: load_account() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Falls jemand die Lösung bzw das gleiche Problem hat / hatte bitte unter diesen Kommentar kommentieren

Answer (score 2):

`IBMQ.load_account()` doesn't take any parameters. It loads the credentials saved locally, if you did a `IBMQ.save_account()` prior. If you want to use the credentials for just a single session, you can use `IBMQ.enable_account(API_TOKEN)`.